# Software for Automatic Remote FTP Backup

Tags: windows-7, backup, ftp

I'm looking for software (free or paid) that could perform a weekly automatic backup to an outside server via FTP.

I've looked around and all I seem to be finding is either garbage shareware or free tools that are no longer supported. The system will be backing up from a Windows 7 desktop system to a Linux CentOS 5 server.

Can someone direct me to a stable, reliable piece of software? This is for business documents so reliability is key.

Comment: Have You tried Fling for automated FTP backup?
Do you know any other good solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Novell's NetDrive client can do this:

Novell NetDrive (includes a download link)
  http://www.theblog.ca/novell-netdrive

WikiPedia - Novell NetDrive
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetDrive

Don't be scared away by the WebDAV stuff, the FTP part of this works very well as it works in the background and has options to synchronize one way or bi-directionally.  With Novell's vast experience in creating virtual network drive letters in their Client32 network client software, you can rest assured that they have already taken care of compatibility issues with file access.

Comment: Excellent! I tried this out and it works perfect. One problem however, batch files that run automatically each night cannot find the drive specified since it doesn't see the drive as local. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Baez:  Batch files can't find the mapped FTP drive?  Which commands are having problems with this?  If your DOS command is for a program that doesn't work with network drives, that could be a cause.

Comment: I'll append the batch script to the question when I'm back from work tonight. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore) + [SMB share](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-samba-configuring.html)

I realize it's not FTP-based, but you can add authentication to your Samba share, achieving effectively the same thing.

Comment: This solution doesn't utilize FTP.  Also, I've had too many bad experiences with Windows Backup (mostly due to incompatibility with newer versions not being able to reliably read archives created by older versions on different versions of Windows), so I don't consider it to be reliable.

Comment: Clearly, as I stated.  OP never mentioned anything about needing to restore to older versions of Windows and specifically indicated Windows 7 is the OS being used. The backup utility as it exists in 7 I have found to be perfectly reliable. We can agree to disagree and let the OP draw his own conclusions.

Comment: I agree, anecdotes can be helpful at times. But for something with a broad base like Windows Backup, it is just FUD.

Comment: @surfasb:  In this case, my anecdote about Windows Backup (a number of my clients experienced this problem; I resolved it with VirtualBox.org, but that's not straight-forward for most people) is relevant because _reliability_ is one of the requirements mentioned in the original question -- since a newer version of Windows often comes with newer hardware that replaces older hardware that failed, backwards compatibility is an important factor for restoring reliably from a backup that was created with an older version of the backup software that isn't compatible with the newer version of the OS.

Comment: @gman:  I didn't mention restoring to an older version of Windows; the problem is that backups created under older versions of Windows sometimes can't be restored under newer versions of Windows.  This is a backward compatibility problem that I've encountered a number of times, and I think it's reasonable to expect that there may come a time (e.g., due to a hardware failure) where the data needs to be restored under a newer OS (running on newer hardware).

Comment: @RandolfRichardson: Yet, for a counter argument, using an anecdotes like "Well, my users have never had problems restoring data, even with using the XP to 7 backup utility" is clearly not helpful in this case.  Best we stick to documented reliability issues.

Comment: @RandolfRichardson: "Just because you didn't experience it doesn't mean that the problem doesn't occur, and my understanding of this web site is that people are encouraged to help each other, especially if that means helping to prevent problems." Yet the same can be said of the fictitious counter argument.

Comment: @surfasb:  I'm sharing real-world experiences that can actually help people; I'm not interested in debating this matter.  Please stop.

Comment: And yet I'm sharing real world situations where anecdotes, traditions, and other cultural entities are not enough. A few samples of observable data goes a log way towards making a solid conclusion.

Comment: @RandolfRichardson: Complete PC Backup backs up to a VHD format which hasn't changed between Windows Vista and Windows 7 making it very reliably, the other option in Windows Backup is also still manually accessible. Please note that the question is about Windows 7, so a 10-year-old-OS and a OS-that-everyone skipped are unlikely to affect the ability to implement the solution provided by this answer. However, it's not sure whether Windows Backup will return with Windows 8; but they'll probably provide a tool to restore the data, which although could be accessed manually anyway...